# Steam wants to download games every time

Tags: linux, steam

Yesterday my Internet connection died suddenly (ISP issues) and was disconnected in the middle of a Dota 2 match, I quickly reconnected with my mobile data and finished the  match, however, every 3 minutes or so, I'd get disconnected with a message that says "No Steam Logon". After finishing the match I closed the game client and powered the PC off. The next morning I tried to play again but I had a 700 MB update so I let it download, however upon reaching 100% it always says that it has "corrupt update files" and wants to download the 700 MB again, it goes on forever.

I have tried everything, from removing cache to reinstalling steam, even the steps provided in the "official" [Update & Installation Issues Basic Troubleshooting guide](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2274-IFLV-5334):

- Restart Computer
- Clear Download Cache
- Repair Library Folder (which doesn't work anymore)
- Verify Local Files
- Change Download Region
- Reinstall Steam
- Move Game Folder

The problem is that now that I have tried to "verify local files" it says that 11,000 files or so failed verification and need to be redownloaded, that is, the entirety of the game in 8.5 GB. I have to mention that I already tried letting it download everything again about 4 times, everytime with the same result: upon reaching 100% it says that it has "corrupt update files" and wants to download everything again.

Fortunately I have had this issue before and happen to have a secondary hard drive running Windows with another dota 2 installation so I would just copy the files over to the download folder of my linux steam library folder and it used to work, but not this time.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: The only thing you appear to have not attempted is to uninstall and then reinstall DOTA2

Comment: I have, and it doesn't work.